# asp.net Refresh base page from iframe

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I have page with other asp.net page inside iframe.

And on button click inside iframe i need to refresh main page from server side.

How can it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make use of javascript and you can easily do it

call the following function on your button click

```
<script language="javascript">
function RefreshParent()
{
window.parent.location.href = window.parent.location.href;
}
</script>
```

From the cs code if you are opening the aspx page in the iframe

```
Page.RegisterStartupScript("RefreshParent","<script
language='javascript'>RefreshParent()</script>");
```

Comment: Page.RegisterStartupScript is obsolete

Comment: @Evgeny - yes but it will work you can use page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript  the new one also

Answer (score 2):

For some reason the javascript function shown in earlier answers did not work for me (although the function was called).  However, this worked for me:

```
    function RefreshParent()
    {
        // Was: window.parent.location.href = window.parent.location.href;
        parent.location.reload(); 
    }
```

I had to add it near the start of my HTML (near the end of the HTML didn't work, as it was not yet rendered).

I used this C# code to call it, which is based on earlier answers but updated to use the current API which has an extra initial paramter, "type":

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "RefreshParent", "<script language='javascript'>RefreshParent()</script>");
```