# refreshing a page after saving a file

Tags: javascript, c#, iframe

I'm new to this so apologies if it's an easy one:

I have a webpage with an iframe in it, the code in the iframe uploads a file to a folder.

Once the file is uploaded I want to refresh the parent page which list the uploaded files.

This is the code that fires to upload the file:

```
void Button1_Click(object Source, EventArgs e){
    if (File1.Value == ""){
        Span1.InnerHtml = "Error: you must enter a file name";
        return;
    }
    if (File1.PostedFile != null){
        try{

            File1.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(Request.QueryString["fpath"]+"\\")+File1.Value);


          Span1.InnerHtml = "File Uploaded";            

        }
        catch (Exception exc){
            Span1.InnerHtml = "Error saving file" + File1.Value + "" + exc.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

I had hope I could just stick a 
    window.parent.location.href = window.parent.location.href;
in after saveas line

Comment: Take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5351342/reload-parent-window-from-within-an-iframe

Answer (score 0):

*This answer is JS, not C#.*

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/954461/2053038), you can use :

`window.top.location.reload();`

EDIT: Your question is tagged as Javascript, and I thought you were using a framework I did not know, however research makes me think this is C#.

Comment: I would say right before `Span1.InnerHtml `but you'll need to somehow send the JS. We might need more details about your problem, but this page could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6368948/asp-net-refresh-base-page-from-iframe

Comment: If I add that into my code after:
     File1.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(Request.QueryString["fpath"]+"\\")+File1.Value);

I just get a server error the page wont display

Answer (score 0):

You could call this function:

```
window.location.reload()
```

After uploading.